# List to a different output

Tags: list

I am doing a minor structure manipulation using python, and have a few issues.

Currently my output is the data below.

```
  [['a', ['b', 'c'], ['d', 'e']], ['h', ['i'], ['j']]]
```

I want to get into this structure below, but my data structure comes out a bit wrong. There could be multiple lists with different entry per list.

```
  (a, b, a, d), (a, c, a, e), (h, i, h, j)
```

What would be the best approach?

Comment: Do you have a formal spec for your problem, that you can add to your question?

Comment: Do you have some code to show us?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick one:

```
from itertools import product, izip

data = [['a', ['b', 'c'], ['d', 'e']], ['h', ['i'], ['j']]]

result = []
for d in data:
    first = d[0]
    for v in izip(*d[1:]):
        tmp = []
        for p in product(*[first, v]):
            tmp.extend(p)
        result.append(tuple(tmp))

print result
```

#### Output:

```
[('a', 'b', 'a', 'd'), ('a', 'c', 'a', 'e'), ('h', 'i', 'h', 'j')]
```